# Why join query containing a sum function returns just 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.  Problem and problem_votes.  There are many rows in the problems table and just one in the votes table.

I have this query:

```
select
   problems.problem_id,
   creator_member_id,
   problem_title,
   problem_description,
   sum( vote ) as totalVotes,
   problem_date
from problems 
left join problem_votes on
problems.problem_id = problem_votes.problem_id
```

I expected there to be returned a list of problems, but I only get one item for some reason.

If I take out the sum function, it returns twenty rows.  Is there a way to get the query to get the sum of the votes for each problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` otherwise it will aggregate the entire table instead of returning one row for each problem_id:

```
SELECT
    problems.problem_id,
    creator_member_id,
    problem_title,
    problem_description,
    sum(vote) as totalVotes,
    problem_date
FROM problems
LEFT JOIN problem_votes
    ON problems.problem_id = problem_votes.problem_id
GROUP BY problems.problem_id
```

This query uses a MySQL extension: [`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Answer (score 2):

`SUM` is an [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function), you need a [`GROUP BY`](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-clause.htm) clause.