# query returning single record if have sum in it

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to retrieve whole records from table and also the sum records from it but the problem is when i use mysql `sum()` function in it its only return a single record and when i remove mysql sum() function it returns the whole records the problem is with sum i google it but couldnt find releative material agains .
I am using codeigniter active records for retrieval of data please point me out where i am making mistak.ty

Here is the my model function.

```
function get_soorh_jama($start_date,$end_date)
{
    $where=array('pe.pur_inv_date >='=>$this->date);
    //$this->db->select_sum('si.chungi');
    $this->db->select('pe.*,px.*,kt.name');
    $this->db->from('purchase_invoice as pe');
    $this->db->join('khata as kt','pe.supplier_id=kt.id');
    $this->db->join('purexpenses as px','pe.pur_inv_id=px.inv_id');
    $this->db->select_sum('pe.nags','sold_nags');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here whats the normal query looks like.

```
SELECT `pe`.*, `px`.*, `kt`.`name`, SUM(`pe`.`nags`) AS sold_nags FROM (`purchase_invoice` as pe) JOIN `khata` as kt ON `pe`.`supplier_id`=`kt`.`id` JOIN `purexpenses` as px ON `pe`.`pur_inv_id`=`px`.`inv_id` WHERE `pe`.`pur_inv_date` >= '10/26/2015'
```

Comment: Pleas take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730777/why-join-query-containing-a-sum-function-returns-just-1-row

Answer (score 1):

use `group by pur_inv_id`

```
SELECT `pe`.*, `px`.*, `kt`.`name`, SUM(`pe`.`nags`) AS sold_nags 
FROM (`purchase_invoice` as pe) JOIN `khata` as kt 
ON `pe`.`supplier_id`=`kt`.`id` JOIN `purexpenses` as px 
ON `pe`.`pur_inv_id`=`px`.`inv_id` WHERE `pe`.`pur_inv_date` >= '10/26/2015' 
group by pur_inv_id
```

Comment: same result its only returning one record and i have multiple records in table at current date

Comment: use **group by pe.supplier_id**

Comment: now returning all rows but it not summing up the column